# Ruby on Rails - List All 3rd Party Library Details & Licensing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundle

My boss has tasked me with the mundane job of listing all 3rd party libraries with version and license for our back end app (rails 4).

eg. Rails 4.2 - MIT

Is there a command to list license along with gems with either of the following or something else? (I'm pretty noob on RoR)
`gem list`
`bundle show`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and not programming.

Comment: It's about a program that will list licensing...

Comment: this one can help https://github.com/Fivell/gemfile_utils

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like (in the rails console)

```
Gem.loaded_specs.each do |name, spec|
  puts "#{name}: #{spec.license}"
end
```

AFAIK, this will only return the license if it is in the gem spec - it won't for example take any notice of a LICENSE file in the source repository. In an app I looked at around a quarter of gems didn't have a license in the gem spec.

Comment: Nice solution, tried it out but as you said lots were missing. Using license_finder I was able to generate all but 4 unknown which I then populated manually.

Answer (score 3):

I found this that seemed to work very well
https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder

```
$ gem install license_finder
$ license_finder
```